# PHP: function to remove/replace all single characters in a string?

Tags: php, string, replace, character

I need a PHP function that removes (or replaces) all *single* characters in a string.

`"A Quick Brown B C D Fox"` -> `"Quick Brown Fox"`

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex:

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('@(^|\pZ)\pL\pM*(?=\pZ|$)@u', ' ', $str));
```

This would remove any single *letter*. If you want to remove any character period, you could do:

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('@(^|\pZ)P\Z(?=\pZ|$)@u', ' ', $str));
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/YaLUQD

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WbV8lI doesn't work on diacritics and leaves a lot of spaces.

Comment: @Alexander Wow, that's interesting.

Comment: I think the solution is right what Dylan was looking for, but since you've placed \pL\pM, I wanted to test it in action to see the difference :).

Comment: @Alex I am stumped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237326/unicode-regexes-with-mb-ereg

Comment: \pL\pM.? works at detecting the diacritic. The dot matches 0x82. The "Ă" character seems to be made of a character that matches \pL, and the second - I have no idea how to match it. It doesn't match either \pL or \pM.

Comment: @Alex That's... Peculiar. I think this might be because `preg_replace`'s support of multibyte strings is broken.

Comment: @NullUserException let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2975/discussion-between-alexandermp-and-nulluserexception)

Comment: The Unicode-category metasequences (`\pL`, `\p{Lu}`, and the like) only work if you add the `/u` modifier: `'@(^|\pZ)\pL\pM*(?=\pZ|$)@u'`

Comment: Why can't you just mb_ereg_replace('\s([^\s]?\s+)+', ' ', ' '.$str.' ') with proper mb_regex_encoding() ? http://ideone.com/mwEUE

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "A Quick Brown B C D Fox";
$array = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    if (strlen($value) == 1)
        unset($array[$key]);
$string = implode(" ", $array);
echo $string;
```

That'll do it - tested it this time. Sorry.

Comment: `\w Match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_")` vs `\s Match a whitespace character` - You seem to have them backwards...